# Fetch real time data using WCF

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, callback

Want the WCF service to communicate to client about a change in data(Configuration in db). I do not have control over DB directly, it is only through this service.

Don't want the client to communicate the WCF service to check if any data change in certain frequency to avoid unwanted traffic.

The client need to be updated whenever the config in db changes.

Is it possible in WCF ? Any references to do it ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's called the **duplex** binding, where both the server and the client can independently send messages to each other. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/duplex-services

Comment: Callback mechanism (callback channel) in WCF best suits your needs. It does not cause unwanted traffic. You can also send a message to a "message queue" (like RabbitMQ) and subscribe your clients to that message queue.

Comment: signalr (for a light fun and family friendly way to communicate with your clients)